# Possible null reference return when checking against default with EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals()

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a method that looks something like this:

```cs
static async Task<T> ExampleMethod<T>()
{
    T? result = default;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            result = await TryToDoSomething<T>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log
        }

        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(result, default) == false)
        {
            return result;
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Visual Studio makes a green squiggly line under result in the return statement saying:`'result' may be null here. CS8603: Possible null reference return.`

I thought when I compare the value to the default value of that type I would catch all possible null values.

Questions:

1. Is the warning correct or is Visual Studio making things up here?
2. If it is correct, how is it possible and in which situations can it appear?

Comment: Well you explicitly say that result is nullable, T? result is just syntactic sugar for <nullable>T.

Comment: @ChrisFromTheBlock
Yes I do, but if I add result != null as a condition the warning disappears:
```
if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(result, default) == false
            && result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }
```

Visual studio is smart enough to find out that it is not possible for result to be null in that case.

Comment: The compiler can't possibly understand every single path to understand null checks. Sometimes you need to give it a hint e.g. `return result!;`

Comment: @DavidG Alright thanks, that's what I have done. But I couldn't stop thinking about this and had to ask.

Comment: Well you specifically declare the value as nullable. So the compiler thinks its nullable and tells you that the result might be null. If you don't want it to be nullable then you shouldn't declare it as nullable. If the default value can be null, then the result can also be null. The comparison doesn't change anything since you set the nullable object to the default value, so you might as well compare null with null, and then result can still be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality comparer is not guaranteed to return false if result is null.

`EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will use the `IEquatable<T>.Equals`-method if this exist, or the `Object.Equals(object)` if not. And if neither is implemented it will use reference equality for reference types, and value equality for value types.

If there are any custom equals methods they could return whatever they want.

If you want to ensure that `result` is not null, just do `result != null`. I think that should work for both value types and reference types.

Do note that `default(int)` will be `0`, and I'm guessing this should be a valid value to return. So comparing with `default` is probably not what you want to do.